# add line break to the label in Tikz

Tags: diagrams, line-breaking, tikz-styles, flow-charts

How can I add line break to the label (description) of diagram in Tikz?
This is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows.meta,calc,chains,shapes.geometric,backgrounds,fit,arrows,positioning}

\tikzset{
  neu/.style={
  draw,
  circle,
  minimum size=1cm,
  },
  declare function={
        sigma(\x) = 1/(1+exp(-\x));
        sigmap(\x) = sigma(\x)*(1-sigma(\x));
    },
  mem/.style={
  draw,
  circle,
  minimum size=0.5cm,
  }
input/.style={coordinate},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex']
    % We start by placing the blocks
    \node [input, name=input1] {};
    %fuzzification
    \node [neu, right = 1.3 of input1, path picture={
    \draw[shift={(path picture bounding box.center)},
        domain=-0.30:0.30, samples=50,red,
    ] plot ({\x},{1*(sigmap(20*\x)-0.1)});
}][label={[xshift=0cm, yshift=0.2cm]\textcolor{blue}{\small Membership function}}] (neu) {};;

\draw [draw,->] (input1) -- node {\footnotesize{$input$}} (neu);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{My caption}\label{fig4}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image]

and this is what I want:
[image]

Comment: Add `align=center` to the options of the label and use ``\\`` to separate the lines. A label is just another node and can be customized the same way.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, make your document example compilable. Missed is comma between style definitions, undefined `sigmap` etc ...

Answer (score 2):

---

Similar to this?

[image]

**Edit:**
Now, when function `sigmap` is known, and remove all errors from your document examples, MWE can be:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                %backgrounds,
                %calc, chains,
                %fit,
                %decorations.pathreplacing,
                quotes,
                positioning,
                %shapes.geometric
                }

\begin{document}
%    \begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=Latex,
node distance = 0mm and 15mm,
   neu/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=1cm},
every label/.append style = {font=\small, text=blue, 
                             align=center}, % added for multi lines labels
every edge quotes/.style  = {auto, font=\footnotesize\itshape, inner sep=1pt},
declare function={
        sigma(\x) = 1/(1+exp(-\x));
        sigmap(\x) = -0.25+2*sigma(\x)*(1-sigma(\x));},                    
                ]
% We start by placing the blocks
\coordinate (in);
\node[neu, right = of in,
      label=Membership\\ function] (neu) {};
\draw[red, thick] plot [domain=-6:6, samples=101] (2 + \x/20,{sigmap(\x)});
%
\draw [draw,->] (in) to["input"] (neu);
    \end{tikzpicture}
%\caption{My caption}
%\label{fig4}
%   \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**   A bit more sophisticated solution:

- function is part of node drawn by use of `append after command` node option:
- function position in node is determined by extract `x` from node name

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, quotes,
                positioning,
                }
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]% <--- for extract x, y coordinates from node name
{%        
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=Latex,
declare function={
        sigma(\x)  = 1/(1+exp(-\x));
        sigmap(\x) = -0.25+2*sigma(\x)*(1-sigma(\x));},
node distance = 0mm and 15mm,
   mem/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=1cm,
    append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
                \gettikzxy{(\LN.center)}{\ax}{\ay}  %<--- for extrax x, x coordinate from \LN
                \draw[red, thick] plot [domain=-7:7, samples=101] (\ax + 1.2*\x,{sigmap(\x)});
                                   }% end \pgfextra
                         }% end append after command
                },
every label/.append style = {font=\small, text=blue, 
                             align=center}, % added for writing of multiline labels 
every edge quotes/.style  = {auto, font=\footnotesize\itshape, inner sep=1pt},
                ]
% We start by placing the blocks
\coordinate (in);
\node[mem, right = of in,
      label=Membership\\ function] (m) {};
% Input arrow
\draw [draw,->] (in) to["input"] (m);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

result is the same as before.

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten. I added the sigmap function to the code.

Comment: @Milito, now image is complete.

Comment: @Milito, see addendum to answer. BTW, now you have two answers, so it may be a time to decided, which one you the most liked and accept it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Zarko's solution, but changing the construction order so that the curve is centered in the circle (The offset of 2 in the function is removed `2 + \x/20,{sigmap(\x)}` --> `\x/20,{sigmap(\x)}`. With a `\ray` command to change the size of this circle and enlarge the curve accordingly.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                %backgrounds,
                %calc, chains,
                %fit,
                %decorations.pathreplacing,
                quotes,
                positioning,
                %shapes.geometric
                }

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\ray}{2}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    auto,>=Latex,
    node distance = 15mm,
    neu/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=\ray cm},
    every label/.append style = {font=\small, text=blue, 
                            align=center}, % added for multi lines labels
    every edge quotes/.style  = {auto, font=\footnotesize\itshape, inner sep=1pt},
    declare function={
        sigma(\x) = 1/(1+exp(-\x));
        sigmap(\x) = -0.25+2*sigma(\x)*(1-sigma(\x));},                    
                ]
\draw[red, thick,scale=\ray] plot [domain=-6:6, samples=101] (\x/20,{sigmap(\x)});
\node[neu,label=Membership\\ function] (neu) {};
\coordinate [left = of neu] (in);
\draw [draw,->] (in) to["input"] (neu);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Example in addendum to my answer has not hardwired distance for placing plot of function in node. There plot is part of node style (well, a wee bit complex code :-) ) and it is independent from node position. You start from my first solution, maybe will be worth to emphasise this ;-). Anyway, +1!

Answer (score 0):

The code proposed give me a lot of errors in execution. So I start with a simplified one:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) circle(3.5);
        \draw[red,line width=2pt] plot[line width=2pt,domain=-3:3] (\x,{1.5*cos(\x r)+1.5});
        \node[align=center,blue] at (0,4.5) {\Large\bfseries Membership\\ \Large\bfseries function};
        \draw[line width=2pt,-latex] (-8,0.5)--(-4,0.5) node[pos=.5,above] () {\large $input$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]